# EC2 can't get to internet? SG and ACL seem OK

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've applied the terraform code below (`variables.tf` and `main.tf` are, of course, separate IRL) to setup an AWS `VPC`, private and public subnets, routes, NAT gateway, Internet Gateway, Network ACLs, an EC2 instance (in the public subnet) with a Security Group attached.

I can ssh into the EC2 just fine, but `apt update` won't complete. `tcpdump` shows `SYN` packets going out `eth0` but nothing coming back. DNS resolution works, and I can ping `10.12.100.1` which is something upstream from `eth0`, I'm not sure what, but that's about it. The EC2 has a private IP on `eth0` which is in the `10.12.100.x` CIDR and an IPv6 address which god only knows what IP is on that.

I've spent the better part of a day redoing `aws_route` and `aws_route_table` resources trying to figure out if I have something wrong there and comparing my resources to the terraform `vpc` module code and I just can't figure it out.

It seems like it should be an `SG` or `ACL` issue but when I look at those configurations in the AWS console, they are as configured, and allowing all egress traffic.

Anyone know what's missing, or how I can troubleshoot this more efficiently?
Thanks

```
############################################################################# 
#                         variables.tf 
#############################################################################

variable "aws_region" {
  description = "AWS region where resources will be created"
  type        = string
  default     = "us-east-2"
}

variable "project" {
  description = "Project tag value for resources"
  type        = string
  default     = "vpc-test"
}

variable "environment" {
  description = "Environment tag value for resources"
  type        = string
  default     = "test"
}

variable "owner" {
  description = "The owner of the project"
  type        = string
  default     = "xyz"  # initials
}

variable "ssh_pub_key" {
  description = "pubkey of the SSH key pair for EC2 instances"
  type        = string
  default     = "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC...9"
}

variable "ingress_cidr_blocks" {
  description = "CIDR blocks to allow for ingress traffic"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["63.9.0.0/16", "64.10.1.1/32"]  
}

variable "vpc_dns_support" {
  description = "Enable DNS support for the VPC"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "vpc_dns_hostnames" {
  description = "Enable DNS hostnames for the VPC"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "vpc_cidr_block" {
  description = "IPv4 CIDR block for the VPC"
  type        = string
  default     = "10.12.0.0/16"
}

variable "subnet_cidr_public" {
  description = "CIDR block for the public end of the subnet"
  type        = string
  default     = "10.12.100.0/24"
}

variable "subnet_cidr_private" {
  description = "CIDR block for the private end of the subnet"
  type        = string
  default     = "10.12.1.0/24"
}

variable "availability_zone" {
  description = "Availability zone for the subnet"
  type        = string
  default     = "us-east-2a"
}

variable "instance_type" {
  description = "EC2 instance type"
  type        = string
  default     = "t2.micro"  # Free tier - could be a policy in spacelift
}

variable "ami_instance" {
  description  = "AMI Instance identifier"
  type         = string
  default      = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776" # Ubuntu 22.04 Server in us-east-2
}


variable "ec2_webserver_data" {
  description = "User data script to initialize EC2 instances"
  type        = string
  default     = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash

    test ! -d /var/www/html && mkdir -p /var/www/html

    # Update package repositories and install tmux and vim
    apt-get update -y
    apt-get install apache2 tmux vim dig -y
    
    echo "<b>Private appserver instance B</b>" > /var/www/html/index.html
    systemctl enable apache2

    # Disable web caching in apache config so subsequent page loads don't conflict 
    cat <<EOT >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header unset ETag
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
            Header set Pragma "no-cache"
            Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    EOT               

    systemctl start apache2       
    EOF
}

variable "ec2_std_data" {
  description = "User data script to initialize EC2 instances"
  type        = string
  default     = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash

    # Update package repositories and install tmux and vim
    apt-get update -y
    apt-get install apache2 tmux vim dig -y
    EOF
}


############################################################################# 
#                         main.tf 
#############################################################################


# Define the provider (AWS)
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}


# the ssh pub key to use --  get from environment variable TV_VAR_ssh_pub_key
resource "aws_key_pair" "my_key_pair" {
  key_name   = "${var.project}-key-pair"  # Replace with the desired key name
  public_key = var.ssh_pub_key
}



# VPC 
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr_block
  enable_dns_support   = var.vpc_dns_support
  enable_dns_hostnames = var.vpc_dns_hostnames

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.project}-TEST-VPC"
    Environment = var.environment
    Project     = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner    
  }
}


# private subnet within the VPC
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block              = var.subnet_cidr_private
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zone
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.project}-PRIV-SUB"
    Environment = var.environment
    Project     = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner    
  }
}

# public subnet within VPC
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block              = var.subnet_cidr_public
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zone
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true     # For public subnet

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.project}-PUB-SUB"
    Environment = var.environment
    Project     = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner    
  }
}


resource "aws_network_acl" "priv_sub_acl" {
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  subnet_ids  = [aws_subnet.private_subnet.id]

  # Define ingress for trusted networks
  ingress {
    rule_no       = 100
    protocol      = "-1"
    action        = "allow"
    cidr_block    = aws_vpc.my_vpc.cidr_block
    from_port     = 0
    to_port       = 0
  }

  # Define ingress (inbound) rules
  egress {
    rule_no       = 100
    protocol      = "-1"
    action        = "allow"
    cidr_block    = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port     = 0
    to_port       = 0
  }
  
  # Tags
  tags = {
    Name          = "${var.project}-PRIV-ACL"
    Environment   = var.environment
    Project       = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner
  }
}


resource "aws_network_acl" "pub_sub_acl" {
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  subnet_ids  = [aws_subnet.public_subnet.id]

  # allow trusted networks ingress
  ingress {
    rule_no       = 100
    protocol      = "-1"
    action        = "allow"
    cidr_block    = var.ingress_cidr_blocks[0]
    from_port     = 0
    to_port       = 0
  }

  # dynamic config for multiple elements of var.ingress_cidr_blocks
  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each  = range(length(var.ingress_cidr_blocks))
    iterator = i
    content {
      rule_no       = 100 + i.value * 100
      protocol      = "-1"
      action        = "allow"
      cidr_block    = var.ingress_cidr_blocks[i.value]
      from_port     = 0
      to_port       = 0
    }
  }

  # Define egress
  egress {
    rule_no       = 100
    protocol      = "-1"
    action        = "allow"
    cidr_block    = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port     = 0
    to_port       = 0
  }

  # Define IPv6 egress rule
  egress {
    rule_no             = 101
    protocol            = "-1"
    action              = "allow"
    ipv6_cidr_block     = "::/0"  # IPv6 CIDR block
    from_port           = 0
    to_port             = 0
  }
  
  # Tags
  tags = {
    Name          = "${var.project}-PUB-ACL"
    Environment   = var.environment
    Project       = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner
  }
}



# Create an Internet Gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "my_igw" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.project}-IGW"
    Environment = var.environment
    Project     = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner    
  }
}

# Elastic IP for the NAT Gateway
resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip" {
  domain           = "vpc"

  # Tags
  tags = {
    Name          = "${var.project}-NATG-EIP"
    Environment   = var.environment
    Project       = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner
  }
}

# NAT Gateway in the public subnet for private resources to reach internet resources
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "my_natg" {
  allocation_id     = aws_eip.nat_eip.id
  subnet_id         = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id  #< NATG needs to reside in pub sub

  # Tags
  tags = {
    Name          = "${var.project}-NATG"
    Environment   = var.environment
    Project       = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner
  }  
  
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.my_igw]
}


# route for private subnet - uses NATG
resource "aws_route_table" "private_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.my_natg.id
  }

  tags = {
   Name = "${var.project}-PRIV-RT"
    Environment = var.environment
    Project     = var.project
    Owner       = var.owner
  }
}

# route to internet for vpc resources
resource "aws_route_table" "public_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  route {
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.my_igw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.project}-PUB-RT"
    Environment = var.environment
    Project     = var.project
    Owner       = var.owner
  }
}


resource "aws_default_route_table" "default_route_table" {
  default_route_table_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.default_route_table_id

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.project}-DEF-RT"
    Environment = var.environment
    Project     = var.project
    Owner       = var.owner
  }
}


# Associate pubsub with pub route
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_route_table.id
  
  # no tags
}

# Associate privsub with priv route
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_route_table.id

  # no tags
}


# Define a security group to allow incoming SSH traffic (adjust rules as needed)
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_sg" {
  name                = "${var.project}-SG"
  description         = "Security group allowing SSH traffic from campus only, egress anywhere"
  vpc_id              = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id 

  # Ingress rule for SSH
  ingress {
    from_port         = 22
    to_port           = 22
    protocol          = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks       = var.ingress_cidr_blocks
  }

  # Egress rule for all IPv4 traffic anywhere
  egress {
    from_port         = 0
    to_port           = 0
    protocol          = "-1"
    cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  # Egress rule for all IPv6 traffic anywhere
  egress {
    from_port         = 0
    to_port           = 0
    protocol          = "-1"
    ipv6_cidr_blocks  = ["::/0"]
  }

  # Tags
  tags = {
    Name          = "${var.project}-EC2-SG"
    Environment   = var.environment
    Project       = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner
  }
}


/*

# Create an EC2 instance in privsub
resource "aws_instance" "my_ec2_instance" {
  ami                     = var.ami_instance
  instance_type           = var.instance_type
  key_name                = aws_key_pair.my_key_pair.key_name
  user_data               = var.ec2_std_data
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  subnet_id               = aws_subnet.private_subnet.id

  metadata_options {
    http_tokens          = "required"
  }

  # Tags
  tags = {
    Name          = "${var.project}-priv1-ec2"
    Environment   = var.environment
    Project       = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner

  }
}


# Create a second EC2 instance in privsub
resource "aws_instance" "my_ec2_instance_b" {
  ami                     = var.ami_instance
  instance_type           = var.instance_type
  key_name                = aws_key_pair.my_key_pair.key_name
  user_data               = var.ec2_std_data
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  subnet_id               = aws_subnet.private_subnet.id

  metadata_options {
    http_tokens          = "required"
  }


  # Tags
  tags = {
    Name          = "${var.project}-priv2-ec2"
    Environment   = var.environment
    Project       = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner
  }
}
*/


# Create a second EC2 instance in pubsub
resource "aws_instance" "my_ec2_instance_c" {
  ami                     = var.ami_instance
  instance_type           = var.instance_type
  key_name                = aws_key_pair.my_key_pair.key_name  # Reference the key name from the aws_key_pair 
  user_data               = var.ec2_webserver_data
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  subnet_id               = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id

  metadata_options {
    http_tokens          = "required"
  }

  # Tags
  tags = {
    Name          = "${var.project}-pub1-ec2"
    Environment   = var.environment
    Project       = var.project
    Owner         = var.owner
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone else who stumbles across this, the ACLs don't know that the SYN-ACK packets coming back from a connection initiated from within an EC2 is traffic that is related to that connection (stateless).

This means you can't just `apt update && apt dist-upgrade -y` without first opening `0/0` on the inbound side of the ACL.